# Add escape character in front of all quotation marks in a file

Tags: sed, vim, escape-characters, json

I have a pretty big json file and I would like to add the escape character in front of all quotation marks in it. For example I want to change: 
`"CaptureDuration":0` to `\"CaptureDuration\":0`. I tried to substitute all `"` with `\"` in sed and vim but I guess due to the special type of the escape character it wasn't working properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `sed` and you needed to escape `\` as it's special character:

```
sed 's/"/\\"/g' infile
```

Comment: it works, thanks a lot for the quick reply